# CSS and different @page for multiple pages

Tags: css, css-print

I have a request to style different pages with different sizes (A3, A2 etc.).

Is there a possibility to use different @pages for different pages with different sizes?

I would need something like this:

```
@page 1{
     
        size: A3 landscape;
        margin-top: 50mm;
        margin-bottom: 50mm;
        margin-left: 0mm;
        margin-right: 0mm;
   
        @top-right {
            content: element(headerPage); 
             border-top:2px solid #434190;
        }
     
        @bottom-right {                 
            content: element(footerPage);
            border-top:2px solid #434190;
        }
      }
```

second page:

```
 @page 2{
             
                size: A2 landscape;
                margin-top: 50mm;
                margin-bottom: 50mm;
                

margin-left: 0mm;
            margin-right: 0mm;
       
            @top-right {
                content: element(headerPage); 
                 border-top:2px solid #434190;
            }
         
            @bottom-right {                 
                content: element(footerPage);
                border-top:2px solid #434190;
            }
          }
```

Also what do I need to change in my  to apply the different pages?

Many thanks.